# Splitting array elements into more elements because of space in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/rfnslyr/Zxav9/1/

I want to input a block of HTML code, and have it extract all CSS classes and ID's, uniquely. Problem is, it treats the following each as a unique single class.

```
<div class="test hello"></div> 
<div class="test hello"></div> 
<div class="test hello bye"></div> 
<div class="test hello bye yes"></div>
```

This is my console output:

```
0:test hello
1:test hello
2:test hello bye
3:test hello bye yes

uniqueNames["test hello", "test hello bye", "test hello bye yes"]
```

Ideally my console output should be the following:

```
0:test hello
1:test hello
2:test hello bye
3:test hello bye yes

uniqueNames["test", "hello", "bye", "yes"]
```

**function**

```
$(function() {
    $('#submitCode').click(function() {
        var CSS_CLASSES = [];
        var CSS_IDS = [];
        var el = document.createElement( 'div' );
        var text = $("#codeInput").val();
        el.innerHTML = text;       
        var nodes = el.getElementsByTagName('*');

        for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            var node = nodes[i];
            if(node.id.length > 0) {
                CSS_IDS.push(node.id); 
            }
            if(node.className.length > 0) {
                CSS_CLASSES.push(node.className);   
            }
        }

        var uniqueNames = [];
        $.each(CSS_CLASSES, function(i, el){
            if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
        });     

        console.log(uniqueNames + " --- " + uniqueNames.length);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rfnslyr/Zxav9/1/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in one line:

`CSS_CLASSES.push.apply(CSS_CLASSES, node.className.split(" "));`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w645W/

Basically, JavaScript's `apply()` calls `push()` and hands it a list of arguments as an array to apply to CSS_CLASSES. `.split(" ")` conveniently provides us an array of terms that were separated by spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the class names on the spaces (`split(/\s+/)`), try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#submitCode').click(function() {
        var CSS_CLASSES = [];
        var CSS_IDS = [];
        var el = document.createElement( 'div' );
        var text = $("#codeInput").val();
        el.innerHTML = text;       
        var nodes = el.getElementsByTagName('*');

        for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            var node = nodes[i];
            if(node.id.length > 0) {
                CSS_IDS.push(node.id); 
            }
            if(node.className.length > 0) {
                var classNames = node.classNamesplit(/\s+/);
                for (var j = 0; j < classNames.length; j++) {
                    CSS_CLASSES.push(classNames[j]);   
                }
            }
        }

        var uniqueNames = [];
        $.each(CSS_CLASSES, function(i, el){
            if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
        });     

        console.log(uniqueNames + " --- " + uniqueNames.length);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You never actually split an array. Use this:

```
    $.each(CSS_CLASSES, function (i, el) {
                console.log(i + ":" + el);
                var splitted = el.split(' ');
                for (var j = 0; j < splitted.length; j++) {
                    if ($.inArray(splitted[j], uniqueNames) === -1)
                       uniqueNames.push(splitted[j]);
                }
            });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zxav9/3/)